# How to improve performance when having a huge list of bytes to be written to file?

Tags: python, performance, optimization

In python, I have a huge list of floating point values(nearly 30 million values). I have to convert each of them as 4 byte values in little endian format and write all those to a binary file in order.

For a list with some thousands or even 100k of data, my code is working fine. But if the data increases, it is taking time to process and write to file. What optimization techniques can I use to write to file more efficiently?

As suggested in [this](http://dabeaz.blogspot.in/2010/01/few-useful-bytearray-tricks.html?m=1) blog , I am replacing all the small writes to a file by the use of bytearray. But still, the performance is not satisfiable.

Also I have tried multiprocessing (concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()) to utilize all the cores in the system instead of using a single CPU core. But still it is taking more time to complete the execution.

Can anyone give me more suggestions on how to improve the performance(in terms of time and memory) for this problem.

Here is my code:

```
def process_value (value):
    hex_value =  hex(struct.unpack('<I', struct.pack('<f', value))[0])
    if len(hex_value.split('x')[1]) < 8:
        hex_value = hex_value[:2] + ('0' * (8 - len(hex_value.split('x')[1]))) + hex_value[2:]

    dec1 = int( hex_value.split('x')[1][0] + hex_value.split('x')[1][1], 16)
    dec2 = int(hex_value.split('x')[1][2]+hex_value.split('x')[1][3],16)
    dec3 = int(hex_valur.split('x')[1][4]+hex_value.split('x')[1][5],16)
    dec4 = int(hex_value.split('x')[1][6]+hex_value.split('x')[1][7],16)
    msg = bytearray( [dec4,dec3,dec2,dec1] )
    return msg

def main_function(fp, values):
    msg = bytearray()
    for val in values:
        msg.extend (process_value(val))
    fp.write(msg)
```

Comment: If you're writing the kind of code where you have 30 million floating-point values, you may want to look into [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/).

Comment: NumPy plus mmap seems like it would be the fastest.

Comment: Can you give a small example for `values`?

Comment: ...what the heck is up with all that hex stuff? The `struct.pack` output should already be what you need. Everything else in `process_value` is redundant.

Comment: The values are like [0.1245332677, -1.5734637835, 1.473683673, ...]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually the code is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try converting all the floats before writing them, and then write the resulting data in one go:

```
import struct    

my_floats = [1.111, 1.222, 1.333, 1.444]    

with open('floats.bin', 'wb') as f_output:
    f_output.write(struct.pack('<{}f'.format(len(my_floats)), *my_floats))
```

For the amount of values you have, you might need to do this in large blocks:

```
import struct    

def blocks(data, n):
    for i in xrange(0, len(data), n):
        yield data[i:i+n]

my_floats = [1.111, 1.222, 1.333, 1.444]    

with open('floats.bin', 'wb') as f_output:
    for block in blocks(my_floats, 10000):
        f_output.write(struct.pack('<{}f'.format(len(block)), *block))
```

The output from `struct.pack()` should be in the correct binary format for writing directly to the file. The file must be opened in binary mode e.g. `wb` is used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Writing in blocks is actually saving time and memory.

Comment: Glad it helped.  When finished, don't forget to click on the grey tick under the up/down buttons to select an answer as the accepted solution.